# Add supported header type to JsonOutputFormatter

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, content-type

My company uses a standard format for healthcheck responses in internal apis etc. We either return the status with a content type of `application/status+json` on success or `application/problem+json` if we have an issue (part of [this proposed spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807)).

But if i set the content type to either of these my response becomes an emptu `406` response.

So, how can I tell the JsonOutputFormatter that it can add these Json header types to it's `SupportedMediaTypes` collection?

I would expect I could do something like:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions => {
    jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/problem+json");
});
```

But of course I can't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here is a way to do it. I found the `OutputFormatters` collection and was able to pull out the JsonOutputFormatter. From there you can add a supported media type:

```
        services.AddMvc(mvcOptions => {
            //TODO: make extension method 
            var jFormatter = mvcOptions.OutputFormatters.FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetType() == typeof(JsonOutputFormatter)) as JsonOutputFormatter;
            jFormatter?.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/problem+json");
            jFormatter?.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/status+json");
        });
```

Or, as an extension method:

```
    public static IMvcBuilder AddStatusJsonSupport(this IMvcBuilder builder) {
        builder.AddMvcOptions(options => {
            var jFormatter = options.OutputFormatters.FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetType() == typeof(JsonOutputFormatter)) as JsonOutputFormatter;
            jFormatter?.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/problem+json");
            jFormatter?.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/status+json");
        });
        return builder;
    }
```

called like so:

```
services.AddMvc().AddStatusJsonSupport();
```